# Can't sort for 3 Digits

Tags: jquery, sorting, html

Hi I use this script work well, my problem is if the price is superior to 2 Digit the sort can't work good.
Exemple : if product price is 120 not sort correctly. You can try here
http://jsfiddle.net/tc5dc/

```
function sortUsingNestedText(parent, childSelector, keySelector) {
var items = parent.children(childSelector).sort(function(a, b) {
    var vA = $(keySelector, a).text();
    var vB = $(keySelector, b).text();
    return (vA < vB) ? -1 : (vA > vB) ? 1 : 0;
  });
  parent.append(items);
}
 sortUsingNestedText($('#sortThis'), "div", "span.price");
```

Thank u to help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are comparing price, you need to cast string to number.

```
function sortUsingNestedText(parent, childSelector, keySelector) {
    var items = parent.children(childSelector).sort(function (a, b) {
        var vA = $(keySelector, a).text();
        var vB = $(keySelector, b).text();
        if (keySelector == 'span.price') {
            vA = Number(vA);
            vB = Number(vB);
        }

        return (vA < vB) ? -1 : (vA > vB) ? 1 : 0;
    });
    parent.append(items);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tc5dc/620/